# Recover partitions with both Windows 7 and Linux installed using TestDisk

Tags: data-recovery, multi-boot, grub2, testdisk, partition-recovery

I need to recover my partitions using TestDisk. I used deep search and the result is as follows:

```
Disk /dev/sdc - 500 GB / 465 GiB - CHS 60801 255 63
     Partition               Start        End    Size in sectors
 D HPFS - NTFS              0  32 33   191  89 26    3072000 [System]
 D HPFS - NTFS            191  89 26   382 146 19    3072000
 D HPFS - NTFS            191  89 27 20760  19 59  330436608 [S3A8721D005]
 D HPFS - NTFS            191  89 27 31154  19 33  497416192 [S3A8721D005]
>* Linux                25737 254 54 35703  70 15  160092160
 D Linux                25740 237 34 35706  52 58  160092160
 D Linux                25741 112 36 35706 182 60  160092160
 D Linux                25744   0  1 35709 254 63  160103790
 D Linux                25752   5 46 35717  76  7  160092160
 D Linux Swap           30725 122 54 31153 242  1    6883328
 D HPFS - NTFS          31154  52  3 45202 251 41  225693696 [Play]
 D HPFS - NTFS          45203  29 11 59264 132  4  225896448 [Work]
 D HPFS - NTFS          59264 132  5 60801  80 15   24688640 [HDDRECOVERY]
```

I understand I'm expected to set the right partition labels using Left/Right arrows to "*=Primary bootable  P=Primary  L=Logical  E=Extended  D=Deleted". However, if I set the windows partitions to * and L, the Linux partitions can't be set to anything but D, thus I'll lose my data there. If I set one of the Linux partitions to *, then no other Windows partition can be set to anything other than D.

I don't need to be able to boot from this drive again, but I need to recover my data there. Can I set the linux partition to *, recover data from there, and then do that again to recover data from the Windows partitions?

When I click P to list the files, TestDisk shows an error message for each of the Linux partitions (bad filesystem).

I think originally the Linux partitions were logical partitions "inside" the primary partition which includes [S3A8721D005], and Play, Work and HDDRECOVERY were on another primary part